# COM class factory for component with clsid failed error 80040154

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, iis-6, 32-bit

I have a weird error when running an asp.net web site.

Everytime i try to run the website, i got this error: "COM class factory for component with CLSID failed due to the following error : 80040154"

I located the dll who is giving me trouble, it's one we developed and never failed before(already used in other sites)

I try every advise on Internet, already try

1. Check the platform target =X86.
2. The OS is WS2003, 32 bits, IIS 6.0 (No need to set the run 32 bits apps).
3. Regsvr32 failed due to Entrypoint was not found.
4. Try to use regasm, succesfuly registered but not success, still send the same error.
5. Check the regedit, found the CLSID, check the value of Default under InProcServer32.
6. Try to use Gacutil, not success
7. Copy the dll into System32 folder
8. Gave FULL permissions on EVERY folder involved or suggested

The weird thing, i got the dll under the BIN folder, so, why it need to be registered?

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: is your DLL using other DLLS? try running regmon etc. to see the Registry access. also, does the error message give a GUID? and you're saying that GUID existed in the registry?

Comment: Thast's right, the error gave GUID {B0138B9E-F703-483A-B499-CE757523E451} and i found it in RegEdit. Gonna try to run regmon to check the use of Registry. And yes, it run another dll but they are also in BIN folder and System32 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tried all the possible culprits, try running regmon and see the dependent DLLs being referenced by the base DLL. and for each of those DLLs, find if the registry entries/registration etc. exist.